# classifying accelerometer data over time in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, accelerometer

I have a set of accelerometer data recordings after 4 different kinds of events (and many repetitions of each).
each point (recording) is defined by 3 vectors (X,Y,Z) with 150,000 samples each (5 seconds with a sample rate of 30KHz). so all in all i have alot of 3x150,000 matrices.

I want to use a classifier or clustering for these points using python in order to see if there is a difference between the behavior of the accelerometer after the different types of events.

1. what is the best classifier to use?
2. how should i structure my data?
3. how do i plot this in order to visualize my data?

thanks a lot to any helpers.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to give you exact pointers as to what you should be doing in terms of data storage. I suppose you have figured this out already? If not it all depends on various parameters, such as the frequency of read/write access to it, the size of the data and other things, such as your DAQ system. For that matter, I assume this is already resolved and the data is already recorded and stored somehow. This can be in a `csv` file, a database or a custom file format. As long as you can read it, it doesn't really matter.

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to structure your data. It is a wrapper around `numpy` and is described as:

> pandas is an open source, BSD-licensed library providing high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools for the Python programming language.

For plotting, since you seem to be doing statistical analysis, either use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) for your basic plotting, or [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) for your clustering and statistical analysis etc. From the Seaborn website:

> Seaborn is a Python visualization library based on matplotlib. It provides a high-level interface for drawing attractive statistical graphics.

Have a look at the [Seaborn gallery](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/index.html), for possible plots. It gives a good overview on the diagrams that are possible with the library as well as the source code that is required for that plot.